# Android Layout editor ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am running Android Studio (put on latest stabel upgrade the other day. When I use the Layout editor it seems to prefer ConstraintLayout. When I move two widgets (one TextView and one button) around it looks all right on the editor, but when I try to it in an emulator device (Nexus 4)  they both ends up in the Upper right corner. Same thing on my real device. Is there some version problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check ConstraintLayout here:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

> When you drop a view into the Layout Editor, it stays where you leave
>   it even if it has no constraints. However, this is only to make
>   editing easier; if a view has no constraints when you run your layout
>   on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the top-left corner).

In other words, it means you must add at least one horizontal and one vertical constraint for the view

Comment: Hi, I got these lines in the xml file.         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="473dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="238dp" 
Is that what I should be looking for?

Comment: ooh I think I get it. These "tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp" " are only for the tool. I thought they reflected the actual position

Comment: Thnx, it works now, by uisng the infer constraint button. Thnx again

Comment: Yes, you are right. These absoluteXY is for editing easier only. Happy coding :)