# Activity not showing correct on emulation

Tags: android

Im new to android but whenever I try to view my activity it is't showing right.

Everything is to the left on the emulated device when I have everything positioned correctly in design view.

[Sorry can't embed yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqmpV.png)

this is the xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.chemdawg.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bio"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:text="Biography"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="533dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pro"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:text="Projects"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="139dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="533dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gam"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:text="Games"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="272dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="533dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="199dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pro"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.395"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you share the activity's layout file?

Comment: Do you want the file or just the code

Comment: just code is fine.

Comment: updated the topic

Comment: Have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017289/buttons-not-visible-on-the-application-whats-wrong, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701340/android-layout-editor-constraintlayout.