# Layout is different than output

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a very simple app that takes a number and squares it just so I can begin playing around with android studio. Why is everything in the corner?

[Screen shot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLgMd.jpg)

SOLUTION:  I had to go change the layout to constraint layout and then selected infer constraints

Comment: android studio design screen, emulator and real devices sometimes are different. You should show the code, I guess you are using RelativeLayout...

Comment: You need to look at the course which explains the basics of xml layouts in Android. If you wanna create layouts for all screens, use some better combinations than just RelativeLayout.

Comment: Have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017289/buttons-not-visible-on-the-application-whats-wrong, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701340/android-layout-editor-constraintlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Check you set the layout orientation to vertical